# Installing debian without a cd/dvd-rom

Tags: debian, installation

Greetings
I want to install debian to my server machine however it doesn't have a cd/dvd rom pluggedin thus I am seeking alternative ways to achieve this.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're already running something on said system, you could do a chroot installation.  If your machine supports boot-to-usb, you can use the usb installer.  If your machine supports PXE you can set up a tftp and bootp server and install over the network.

There are many options.  Google for "debian alternate install" to get a good set of instructions.  Or decide on one and ask for help in that fashion.

I'm a huge fan of using usb to do the install.  It's very like a cd in that you can use the usb disk as a rescue disk, but you can update it :)

Link with way too many ways to install Debian http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Debian/installers.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [install debian via usb](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can install from Grub/Lilo.  I have done this on several occasions with success.  [Link](http://forum.freespire.org/showthread.php?p=116697#post116697)

Answer (score 0):

-If you have a server, where you can install a tftp server, boot pxe is very interesting : http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX

-You can use USB with UNetbootin : unetbootin.sourceforge.net

-You can mount an iso image : howtoforge.com/installing_linux_without_cd_or_dvd

-Or (i don't know what do you have actually on your server), you can use an '.exe' to install Debian via a Windows : goodbye-microsoft.com